# How can I run a Python script inside a webpage?

Tags: python, html, heroku, interaction

I hope you can help me. I have a static website hosted on Heroku and I would like to implement a Python Script to be executed when a button is clicked. So, just as a reference you would have:

- A text field
- A button
- Another text field

The idea is that you enter some text in the first text field, you click the button calling the Python Script, and then print the result coming from the Python Script in the second text field.

How would you implement such technology? Which services should be used to achieve the result?

I think that the script should be hosted somewhere and be called via an API but I do not really know how to do it. I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the lightweight [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) and call your script from there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use backend for your purpose. When a user clicks your button some data would be collected by your backend, handled and showed to user with the help of API. You can start with learning a little bit of Flask and learning Django later for some bigger projects.

Answer (score 1):

I should use Flask or Django. In Flask you simply use the: `name = "your_variable"` command in your HTML code and then you can simply use the code `request.form ["your_variable"]` in your python script.